# Restcomm Android SDK - helloworld and toolbar issue

Tags: android, restcomm

I'm trying to build and run the helloworld example from Restcomm Android SDK.  I have an issue with the toolbar, sometimes it appears after application startup but then it disappears, other time it is not displayed at all.

I'm running SDK from git master on my Honor 7 phone (Android 6).

I read about similar issues with the toolbar (action bar) and perhaps the code should be updated to use Toolbar as described here?

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I think you 're right mehturt. The hello world sample could be updated in that respect. Would you like to contribute that part? I think we are doing it correctly in the olympus application, so it should be pretty straight forward

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning the olympus app, I'll have a look there.